# I want to uninstall ubuntu but my mac reads my Live USB as if it was the linux partition not the installer?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall, live-usb, macbook, partitioning

So I am trying to uninstall Ubuntu Linux from my mac. I am trying to use the Live USB to go into the gparted app to delete the linux partitions.

Although, something strange is happening. When my Live USB is plugged in, and I restart my macbook and hold the option key in the start up screen, I get two hard drive icons. One says windows (which is the linux partition), and the other one is reFit. I choose reFit and then I choose boot from legacy (it is the new icon that pops out and it even has an icon telling me it is an external not internal hard drive). However, when I enter it, the linux installer screen does not show up. Instead, I am asked if I want to boot linux normally, recovery mode, and all those other options. When I choose to start normally, it takes me to my old login screen and has my username and all my **** in there. IT IS NOT THE LINUX INSTALLER FROM MY LIVE USB! IT IS THE ACTUAL LINUX PARTITION. The same happens when I choose all other linux icons I get on my start up screen.

why is this? why is linux reading my live USB like as if it were the actual linux partition on my mac? I really do want to uninstall linux from my mac.

(I set it to dual booted. and I have uninstalled it before and installed it again using the same Live USB. It worked before why not 6 months later?)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I dont have Linux installed on a mac, so I am not sure but there are two thing I would try:

- maybe you can just format the ubuntu partition from the mac operating system? I can not help you further with that.
- Maybe your usb is not installed correctly. [Check your download](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) (or re download) and reinstall the USB and try again.