# Are there others methods to uninstall linux on mac?

Tags: command-line, partitioning, uninstall, macbook, alternative

So I am trying to delete my ubuntu linux partition on my macbook because I dont want it there anymore. Yes, I know i can do it using my LIVE USB/CD but I am tired of trying to do that because my computer is not reading it well. I've done it before. I don't know why it is not working now. I explained it all here

[I want to uninstall ubuntu but my mac reads my Live USB as if it was the linux partition not the installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411972/i-want-to-uninstall-ubuntu-but-my-mac-reads-my-live-usb-as-if-it-was-the-linux-p)

that is the link to my previous question for trying to make my live USB readable as a installer.

anyways..

My question now is, are there other alternatives to deleting that partition?
Is there anything I can do on mac's terminal to delete it for example?

I am a noob though. So using terminal will be a good lesson if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

hmm sorry but no command line but it'll work go to "disk utility" in your macos

go to partision tab select the linux partition and then click the minus sign and now select the mac partition and drag into the empty space and you are done :)

Comment: and don't forget to "Apply"

Comment: nope. Does not work. :/
I got an error saying

Partition failed
Partition failed with error:
MediaKit Reports no such partition. 

by the way, I managed to delete the linux partition's content and now I have an extra partition on my Mac OS desktop. I can't merge it with the original mac partition on disk utility. When I try to, I get that error. I used the terminal to delete it. and this is the command I used.

sudo diskutil eraseVolume JHFS+ deleteme /dev/disk1s4